# can I access the fliesmaterial in blotter.js to make them scatter on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, particle-system

i am new to javascript mad WebGL content. recently I came across this library blotter.js. I wanted to make something like this https://animal.cc/. I have made the text made up of flies material which looks exactly like the website. whose code is as follows

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bradley/Blotter/master/build/blotter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bradley/Blotter/3007fe6e/build/materials/fliesMaterial.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
container = document.getElementById("main");
var text = new Blotter.Text("hey how are you",{
    family: "serif",
    size:60,
    fill: "#fff",
    paddingLeft: 80,
    padingRight: 80,
    paddingTop: 80,
    paddingBottom: 80
});
var material = new Blotter.FliesMaterial();
material.uniforms.uPointCellWidth.value = 0.007;
material.uniforms.uPointRadius.value = 0.5;
material.uniforms.uSpeed.value = 2;

var blotter = new Blotter(material, {
    texts: text
});

var scope = blotter.forText(text);
scope.appendTo(container);
```

what I want to do is that, when ever I hover the text it gets erased and new text appears out of animation.
Can you please help me in this problem :))